# Where Should MVP Presenters Be Stored in an ASP.NET web app?

Tags: asp.net, mvp

Where should presenters be stored in an ASP.NET using the MVP pattern in a web app?  Should it be stored in the..

- .. ViewState
- .. Session
- .. or should it be static?
- .. or recreated with every postback?

Comment: They would not be stored anywhere. There are recreated on every postback and wired up with a view that is created (aspx,ascx)

Comment: Ohhh... Thanks. I'd accept it if you posted it as an answer. I'd just like a lead on how others do it as I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They would not be stored anywhere. There are recreated on every postback and wired up with a view that is created (aspx,ascx)